# How to display sets and params pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I have an Abstract model which loads the data from a .dat file,

```
set T := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
set F := f1 f2 f3;
set K := A B C;
set S := I II III IV;
set C := f2 f3;

param D_k  :=
A 1
B 1
C 1;

param A_k  :=
A 1
B 1
C 1;
```

and I want to be able to visualize the sets and params that I am calling from the .dat file in the .py file, which looks like this:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
from coopr.pyomo import *
from objbrowser import *
import os
model = AbstractModel()

model.T = Set()
model.F = Set()
model.K = Set()
model.S = Set()
model.C = Set()

model.D_k = Param(model.K)
model.A_k = Param(model.K)
```

I am working with spyder but in the variable explorer nothing shows up, and I have also tried to use model.pprint but I get this:

```
4 Set Declarations
C : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
F : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
K : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
S : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed

2 Param Declarations
A_k : Size=0, Index=K, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
    Not constructed
D_k : Size=0, Index=K, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
    Not constructed

6 Declarations: F K S C D_k A_k
```

In this image appears the problem I have when running
[image]

Does anyone know how to be able to see the sets and params in order to know if they are being well imported and called in the .py file?

Thank you very much in advance, Cristobal

Comment: You should create a concrete instance of the model using the `model.create()` function. I don't work a lot with AbstractModel, so I'll let a member of the team who does answer it.

Answer (score 3):

In your script, `model.pprint()` is being applied to a model that has not been constructed yet; you need to explicitly tell it to load the data. That's why you're just seeing declarations that say `Not Constructed`.

To construct your model within a script, you can use `create_instance`. So, where `'abs_data.dat'` is the name of your data file:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()

model.T = Set()
model.F = Set()
model.K = Set()
model.S = Set()
model.C = Set()

model.D_k = Param(model.K)
model.A_k = Param(model.K)

instance = model.create_instance('abs_data.dat')
instance.pprint()
```

Running this gives the output:

```
5 Set Declarations
    C : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=2, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['f2', 'f3']
    F : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
    K : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['A', 'B', 'C']
    S : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=4, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']
    T : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=10, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(1, 10)
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

2 Param Declarations
    A_k : Size=3, Index=K, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          A :     1
          B :     1
          C :     1
    D_k : Size=3, Index=K, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          A :     1
          B :     1
          C :     1

7 Declarations: T F K S C D_k A_k
```